# try and except method to disable error messages

Tags: python, django

I'm getting AttributeError at /add_post/'NoneType' object has no attribute 'src'
whenever I don't provide url which is not a required field. I just want to use try and catch method so I don't get this error again.

```
def extract(url):
    g = Goose()
    article = g.extract(url=url)
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
    return article.top_image.src
```

the error is occurring from `resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}`

the problem of implementing try and except I'm facing is that when I'm getting this error I want some default image to be displayed, but don't know how....if you can help me I would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply check whether top_image is none.

```
if article is not None:
    if article.top_image is not None:
        return {'image':article.top_image.src}

return {'image':'default image'}
```

Comment: I still get list index out of range, but I think your soltuion is the way to fix the problem I had

Comment: Check whether article is not None first.

Comment: do you mind looking over thishttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603640/indexerror-at-add-post-list-index-out-of-range-what-does-this-error-meantry

Answer (score 0):

If that's the only error then:

```
try:
    resposne = {'image':article.top_image.src}
except AttributeError:
    resposne = some_image_object
```

Comment: I think it's nicer to check whether article or article.top_image is None, rather than catching the exception. Although that is what he/she asked for.

Comment: The user is asking for try/catch, so I answer with try/catch =D. AFAIK, try/catch is (just a tiny bit) faster than checking for some condition before doing something.

Comment: @I didn't know if/else is faster

Comment: @BCartolo, you're right, in this test if/else is faster, i thought it was the other way around.

Comment: So I read a bit, and try can be faster if the exception occurs few times (proportionnaly). Tested this "same" code, and in my computer, the time was similar when ~4% of the time, the exception was called. If less than 4% of the time, then try/except was faster. https://repl.it/Bbjb/0 --> in here, the breaking point was around 3% of the time.

Comment: Very interesting. Thanks for the example. I will keep it in mind.