# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'src'

Tags: python, django, goose

If I'm not wrong, I think this error mean I'm trying to display that doesn't exist. But I've provided the content, I don't know why I get this error. I'll explain in detail: I'm using django-ckeditor, and when I try to post image and text, they are grouped as content. And I'm trying to use image only to thumbnail it to the front page, separate from the content. So I'm using python goose to extract that image from content. 
in models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    content = RichTextUploadingField(config_name='default')
    @property

    def thumbnail(self):
        g = Goose()
        thumbnail = g.extract(raw_html=self.content).top_image.src
        return thumbnail
```

in html

```
<img src="{{ post.thumbnail }}" />
```

The error dissapears if I do def thumbnail(self, content) (and nothing gets displayed) but I shouldn't do that since I'm extracting from Post model, and that content which is self.content.

Comment: related maybe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34600057/try-and-except-method-to-disable-error-messages/34600103

Comment: hmm that's for extracting from url tho, i'll try that just in case

Comment: The error itself is pretty clear:  You were trying to evaluate `None.src`, which means `top_image` was `None`.  So that's what you need to debug.

Comment: @TomKarzes, yes that's what's confusing me because image is there. I tried posting image in content so it's there. it shouldn't be def thumbnail(self, content) right?

Comment: Try saving `top_image` in a variable before attempting to extract `src` from it.  Then you can test for `None` and backtrack from there.

Comment: I'm following this mainly, https://dpaste.de/cFy6 it has worked last time. not sure why it won't work this time. this time if src is none I don't want anything to show up

Comment: @TomKarzes, the image is already being saved in content. and I'm extracting from there

Comment: Well there must be cases where it's `None` that aren't being caught.  Either that, or else the error is coming from some different part of the code that wasn't shown.